# Fatal error after power outage during git svn fetch

Tags: git, git-svn

I've had a `git svn fetch` of a large SVN repository (over 10,000 commits and 100 branches) going for several days and running overnight.

Overnight, there was evidently a power outage, so the computer was off in the morning, and when turned on gave the Windows message about an unexpected shutdown.

Now, when I try to resume the `git svn fetch` operation, I'm getting an error:

```
fatal: bad config line 1 in file .git/svn/.metadata
fatal: bad config line 1 in file .git/svn/.metadata
fatal: bad config line 1 in file .git/svn/.metadata
fatal: bad config line 1 in file .git/svn/.metadata
config svn-remote.svn.reposRoot https://svn/svn/xxxxxx: command returned error: 128
```

Any idea what is the cause of this error, and a simple solution? (I don't want to have to start the fetch over again, since it will take several days.)

This is git 2.18.0.windows.1 running on Windows 7.

Comment: I found [this mailing group post](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.msysgit/19950) with a nearly identical circumstances and message, and the responder says "I fear that you will have to restart the process. Sorry!"

Comment: I guess your files are truly massive in size, since there's no reason a 10k commits repo would take that long to fetch...

Comment: Running `git-svn` on Windows is **very** slow compared to Linux. Try to do the conversion on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

The `.git/svn/.metadata` file contains only some settings in the usual `git config` syntax. Example:

```
; This file is used internally by git-svn
; You should not have to edit it
[svn-remote "svn"]
    reposRoot = http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf
    uuid = 13f79535-47bb-0310-9956-ffa450edef68
    branches-maxRev = 843846
    tags-maxRev = 843846
```

So you can just start a new conversion process in a temporary directory, stop it immediately and copy the file to the first repository adapting the `maxRev` numbers.

The `maxRev` number are the last revision `git svn` converted. If you have a log of the conversion run or you can extract them from the `git-svn-id:` footer in the newest commits.

Comment: Nice, worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try opening the logged file `.git/svn/.metadata`? Does it look fine? If not, can it be corrected?

Those are the first things I'd try, even before searching mail-lists.